# drag and drop jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag the boxes from the man to the top of the car, target div called 'droppable'. This seems to work when previewing from Dreamweaver but not when previewing in jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dantest2014/9JTSQ/7/

```
$(function () {

var dfd1 = $.Deferred();
var dfd2 = $.Deferred();


$("#lft_box_layer").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move"
});
$("#rgt_box_layer").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move"
});
$("#btm_box_layer").draggable({
    revert: "invalid",
    cursor: "move"
});

$("#droppable").droppable({

    accept: "#lft_box_layer, #rgt_box_layer, #btm_box_layer",



    // tolerance can be set to 'fit', 'intersect', 'pointer', or 'touch'
    tolerance: 'intersect',
    // Add .hoverClass whenever #draggable is being hovered over #droppable
    over: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').addClass('hover');
    },
    // Remove .hoverClass whenever #draggable is no longer hovered over #droppable
    out: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hover');
    },
    // Add .dropClass whenever #draggable is dropped on #droppable
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').removeClass('hover').addClass('drop');


        $('.ui-draggable-dragging').draggable('option', 'disabled', true);


        $("#car").attr('src', "images/removals-car-break.jpg");


    }

});
```

});

Can someone help me with this?

After the three boxes have been dragged to the top of the car I would like to trigger a change of car image and also change the text.

Any help with any part of this question would be great. 
Thanks! 
Dan

Comment: draggable/droppable are jQuery UI features, which is not included in your jsFiddle

Comment: previewing from dreamweaver, huh, how that worked..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to preview it on JSFiddle you first need to implement jQueryUI (not just jQuery) on the project.

Here is the same example with jQueryUI bound into your project (and cleaned the code a little to not waste code calling the draggable for all of the elements): http://jsfiddle.net/9JTSQ/11/

```
    $(".toDrag").draggable({
        revert: "invalid",
        cursor: "move"
    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({    
        accept: ".toDrag",
        .....................    
    });
```

I just bound jQueryUI from its [CDN](http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js) in "external resources"

Comment: That makes sense as I included the code for the CDN in Dreamweaver but not jsfiddle. Many thanks!

Comment: Great it could help you. From now on try to use general selectors like a class to manage all the elements with the same script. If you have specific selectors like IDs, you can concatenate them into a single jQuery selector like: $("#ID1,#ID2,#ID3").method();